# why does my if statement work if it shouldnt?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i working in asp.net, i am not very familiar with html and c# since the prof really doesnt go over much until it comes up in class.. i do understand it is very similar to java which i am quite familiar with so im not sure what my error is

i have an if statement for a click event to check the selected index of the checkbox list to make sure the right answers are chosen. it works somewhat right but for some reason whenever the first index is selected it makes it right which i dont understand. so really my issue is the selection of the first index causing some sort of issue with the if statement

here is my code for the event handler of the button..

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex.Equals(1)) { 
    LabelResult1.Text = "Question 1 Correct"; 
}
else { 
    LabelResult1.Text = "Question 1 Incorrect"; 
}

if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex.Equals(1)) { 
    LabelResult2.Text = "Question 2 Correct";
}
else { 
    LabelResult2.Text = "Question 2 Incorrect"; 
}

if (CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndex.Equals(0&2&3)) { 
    LabelResult3.Text = "Question 3 Correct"; 
}
else { 
    LabelResult3.Text = "Question 3 Incorrect"; 
}

//write if statement to create image for fireworks
if(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex.Equals(1)&&RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex.Equals(1)&&CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndex.Equals(0 & 2 & 3)) {
    ImageFireworks.ImageUrl = "Images/giphy.gif";
}
```

i also have it so the gif appears if all questions are answered correctly. same the if statement, same issue is happening with it that anytime the 0 index of the checkbox is selected, they appear

Comment: Your code `0&2&3` equals 0. As Tom said below, `&` is a bitwise operator.

Comment: Which one exaclty is not working? And what do you mean by first item the item at index 0? Additionally, I think this one is not doing the thing you believe it does: `Equals(0&2&3)` the  `&` operator does a bitwise AND in c#.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Single `&` is the bitwise AND operator so `0 & 2 & 3` evaluates to 0 which makes your expression work like `SelectedIndex.Equals(0)`. In order to check for multiple selected items, you have to check the `.Selected` property of each item like:

```
CheckBoxList1.Items[0].Selected && CheckBoxList1.Items[2].Selected && CheckBoxList1.Items[3].Selected
```

Comment: Should be `||` here.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It's up to the business logic if all checkboxes should be checked or just one. I guessed it should be logical `AND` instead of `OR` since `&` was used by OP who wrote he's familiar with Java so he'd have used `|` if he meant `OR` (which of course wouldn't give him desired results).

Answer (score 3):

`CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndex.Equals(0&2&3)` will evaluate to true for a index = 0 because `0&2&3` is zero. This is because in c# the [`& operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator) is a bitwise AND.

- 0 = b00000000
- 2 = b00000010
- 3 = b00000011

These three combined with an binary AND operator (like you did) will result in 0.